# Could someone please identify this bike and tell me the cost/price?

Tags: identify-this-bike

[image: Black bicycle with the words "Schwinn" and "Frontier" on the frame]

I found this bike in a junkyard, perfectly functional and looking like it hadn't been used in awhile. I brought it home and cleaned it up a little; I googled everywhere online but I can't find this exact bike and I'd also like to know the price.

Comment: Questions seeking product/service/learning material recommendations or item valuations are off-topic because they tend to become obsolete quickly. Instead describe the situation or specific problem you are trying to solve, or try chatting about it in The Velodrome.

Comment: I will note that Schwinn is still a modestly good low-medium priced brand -- better than an no-name, at least.  That one's probably 10-20 years old.  You can't sell it for much, but it should be a decent bike, if nothing's busted on it.

Comment: Looks like a perfectly adequate bike to ride.  Do a good safety check over it, make sure the brakes work and the tyres hold air, and that nothing is obviously wrong, and give it a test ride.    Would make a fine commuter or school bike or small shopping runs.

Comment: Maybe it's just the angle of the fork rake in the picture, but the front fork seems to be shot, recessed towards the back of the bike as if the bike hit something frontally and the fork got bent. Might be the reason why the bike ended up on the junkyard. Make sure to get this checked.

Comment: @ttarchala good spotting!  I think its the angle of the wheel, the camera angle, and the width of the crown shoulders making it look bad.  But its totally right to look closer.  OP, when the front wheel is straight, there should be a visual straight line down the head tube, and the fork blades/tines should be on this line or forward, but not behind.

Comment: @maggiedong the close votes are because you're asking about valuations.  We can't give useful information because its subjective, and varies depending on locality and supply.     If you have questions about how to repair a bike, that is on topic and we can help there.  But valuations are off-topic as per the [tour] which is worth a quick browse.

Comment: It says what it is on the bike....

Answer (score 2):

It's a Schwinn Frontier circa late 90s. You can read the branding on the tubes and the 90s part comes from the rigid fork and similar matches in Google image search.

> I googled everywhere online but I can't find this exact bike and I'd also like to know the price.

The price evaluation is discouraged on Bicycles SE, but knowing the model you can look for ads and see what other people sell/buy it for.